# Android EditText setHint programmatically not working

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have the following code - When `EditText` is under focus I want the hint disappear, else display it back. In the debug I see that the `EditText` has and lose focus correctly (The `setHint` code line is executed) but the hint is not displayed (the hint removes but not comes back in lost focus). I double checked other places in the code and I don't overwrite it with something that erases the hint except in the `hasFocus` below.

```
editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (hasFocus) {
            editText.setHint(getString(R.string.empty_string));
        } else {
            editText.setHint(getString(R.string.hint_string));
        }
    }
}); 

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:hint="@string/hint_string"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textColorHint="@color/white"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
    android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
    android:paddingLeft="24dp"
    android:paddingRight="24dp"
    android:elevation="3dp"
    android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
    android:background="@color/primary_accent"
    android:layout_below="@id/main_activity_toolbar"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps:

```
        editText.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                editText.setHint("");
                return false;
            }

        });

        editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (!hasFocus){
                    editText.setHint("Hint");
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: @michael I used onTouchListener for checking edittext is active or not.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
< EditText
    android:id="@+id/show_time_search_text"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@color/full.tranparent"
    android:cursorVisible="false"
    android:hint="Your hint text"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textColorHint="#c6c6c6"
    android:textSize="14.2dp" />
```

Comment: So, when you type something,  hint is not disappearing?

Comment: it disappears, the problem is when the edittext loses focus - the hint not come back

Comment: it should appear again, i have used the same in my project, and its working fine. Try removing code for edit text frm your program and use the same layout.

Comment: that's what I did and it's not working. Anyway in your code you lose cursor - I do need the cursor, and this seems to be the single difference between our codes